# Highcharts putting extra space among legend items

Tags: javascript, highcharts, space, legend

I am using highcharts and I am trying to display some exxtra space between legend items for example the legend should look like

school
teacher

tennis
basketball
football

paper
pen

so basically some extra space like item grouping. Does anyone know is this possible to do?

Answer (score 11):

You can provide margin between two legend items in Legend options.

Try:

```
legend: {
    ..// other options
    itemMarginTop: 5,
    itemMarginBottom: 5
}
```

Read more: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.padding